# Can create Ev3 VM, but cannot put VM in availability set

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

**Edit:** I didn't mention that I was creating a Standard_DS1_v2 in the same availability set I was using to create the Standard_E2S_v3, and in that order. When I create the Standard_E2S_v3 first everything works, including creating the v2 VM. Perhaps the availability set is being allocated to old hardware when I specify the v2, and therefore cannot support the v3? (But when I create the v3 first it can support the v2 stuff). Or maybe my understanding of availability sets is flawed? I am hoping to not mark as answered until there is a more clear a reason as to why this is happening.

I am trying to create a Standard_E2S_v3 within an availability set, but the Azure Python SDK is giving the error:

```
Unable to create the VM 'swarm-000-vm-001' in availability set 'swarm-000-aset' because the requested size Standard_E2s_v3 is not available in the current hardware cluster. The available sizes are: Standard_DS1_v2,Standard_DS2_v2,Standard_DS3_v2,Standard_DS4_v2,Standard_DS5_v2,Standard_DS11_v2,Standard_DS12_v2,Standard_DS13_v2,Standard_DS13-4_v2,Standard_DS13-2_v2,Standard_DS14_v2,Standard_DS14-8_v2,Standard_DS14-4_v2,Standard_DS15_v2,Standard_F1s,Standard_F2s,Standard_F4s,Standard_F8s,Standard_F16s,Standard_DS2_v2_Promo,Standard_DS3_v2_Promo,Standard_DS4_v2_Promo,Standard_DS5_v2_Promo,Standard_DS11_v2_Promo,Standard_DS12_v2_Promo,Standard_DS13_v2_Promo,Standard_DS14_v2_Promo,Standard_DS11-1_v2,Standard_DS12-1_v2,Standard_DS12-2_v2. Read more on VM resizing strategy at https://aka.ms/azure-resizevm.
```

However, [the ESv3 series is marked as available in canadacentral](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/services/), and I had no issues creating one without an availability set.

My question is, is it possible to create an ESv3 VM in an availability set in the canadacentral region? If not, when will it be possible, if ever?

Comment: Could you show your code? Also, could you create a Standard_E2S_V3 VM with avaliablity set on Portal?

Comment: I can able to create Availability Set for ESV3 series VM in Canada Central. Are you talking about Availability Set or Availability Zone (HA)?

Note: You can create a new availability set or select an existing availability set in the same location and resource group as the VM.

Comment: I was putting together some source code to post, but when I ran it it worked and created the VM. I did some debugging and the issue appears to be that I am creating a Standard_DS1_v2, then a Standard_E2S_v3. If I create them in the opposite order it works. Maybe the Standard_DS1_v2 is putting the availability set on some older hardware that can't support v3? Or maybe my understanding of availability sets is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new availability set or select an existing availability set in the same location and resource group as the VM.

I was able to create Availability Set for ESV3 series VM in **Canada Central**.

[image]

In case, if you are talking about Availability Zones.

**Note:** All the regions do not support Availability Zones.

ESV3 series support Availability Zones in "**France Central**".

Regions that support Availability Zones

- US Central
- France Central
- East US 2 (Preview)
- West Europe (Preview)
- Southeast Asia (Preview)

For more details, refer [Overview of Availability Zones in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/availability-zones/az-overview).

Comment: This is wrong answer. OP could not create a VM in Availability set not Availability Zones.

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT You can create a new availability set or select an existing availability set in the same location and resource group as the VM. I hope it should be Availability Zone.

Comment: Yes, I can see this. But according to the error log, it is not related with Availability Zones. Also, on Portal, it just a warning, not a error.